# Bulk updating Execution Type in Testlink

Tags: test-management, testlink

In the project I am currently working on, there are more than 1000 testcases where the Execution type is set as Manual, as the project was tested manually for the last few years. With the initiation of mine, the project was totally automated and bridged(integrated) with an automation framework. while integrating the automation framework (Selenium based) with the TestLink.

Therefore with the initiation of automating all the testcase through the script, 
 I am in need of updating Execution type from **Manual** to  **Automated** in all the testcases in bulk.

**Execution type : Manual** --> **Execution type : Automated**

[image: ExecutionType]

Is there any particular method that can be done to change the Execution Type **in-one-go**? 
 (without changing each testcase individually as it consumes a considerable amount of time)

Comment: Try something listed below: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/06/automate-testlink-test-case-result.html Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the complete test cases to an xml file and then replace all Manual keyword with the Automated Keyword(You can do the bulk replace by using any of the text editor). Then again import these test cases to the test link.